# Doctrine Repository vs Private Members

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, datamapper

I am currently trying to retrofit a database with Doctrine, but in the current implementation, not many bi-directional relationships exist between the table. This makes it difficult to traverse the object graph from any given entity.

Let's say I want to be able to start at any given point and traverse the entire object graph. From reading the documentation, I can:

1) Rebuild the database with bi-directional relationship fields so that I can traverse using properly set-up Association Mapping

2) Create custom repositories and fetch by passing in various entities

I'm apprehensive to create bi-directional relationships everywhere, but at the same time, creating many custom repositories give me a bad feeling. What is the rule of thumb when deciding to use associative mapping vs repositories? Is there any performance advantages from one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

You can still traverse unidirectional associations between entities by constructing your queries using fetch joins. This way, the related entities are included in the hydrated result set returned by the query.

If you still need to traverse the object graph more deeply on the inverse side, you can add another join to your query that references the associated entity of the inverse. From a performance standpoint, unidirectional fetch joins are generally preferable to converting the associations to bidirectional because this way you have control over which related entities are loaded and when.

Also note that even if you did convert the associations to bidirectional, you're not actually "rebuilding the database." You would only be adding new properties to the inverse sides of your relationships. This wouldn't add any new fields to the database itself.

As for adding/using custom repositories, this wouldn't add any overhead to your application, per se. Custom repositories are simply places to store queries and other domain logic specific to a given entity. In fact, coding custom queries in your repository classes could be more efficient than trying to query using only default repository methods such as find() and findAll(), which automatically load related entities whether you need them or not.